# permissions on ftp'd files don't seem to match umask

Tags: ftp, umask

I've read several postings indicating that ftp respects the user's **`umask`**. I don't see that that is the case. this is what happens on my server X when I FTP a file from SystemX, to SystemX. SystemX is a Solaris system, my umask is 002, the default umask in **`/etc/profile`** is also 002. Below are the results. The two questions are, why does the ftp'd file not respect my umask, and where is it actually getting it's settings from?

```
**SystemX:/home<username>: umask
02
SystemX:/home<username>: grep umask /etc/profile
umask 02
SystemX:/home<username>: touch junk
SystemX:/home<username>: ls -l junk
-rw-rw-r--   1 <username>  infadev        0 Jan  4 16:24 junk
SystemX:/home<username>: ftp SystemX
Connected to SystemX.
220 SystemX FTP server ready.
Name (SystemX:<username>): <username>
331 Password required for <username>.
Password:
230 User <username> logged in.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> put junk junk.out
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for junk.out.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp> bye
221-You have transferred 0 bytes in 1 files.
221-Total traffic for this session was 383 bytes in 1 transfers.
221-Thank you for using the FTP service on SystemX.
221 Goodbye.
SystemX:/home<username>: ls -l junk*
-rw-rw-r--   1 <username>  infadev        0 Jan  4 16:24 junk
-rw-r--r--   1 <username>  infadev        0 Jan  4 16:24 junk.out
```

Comment: The ftp server maintains its own `umask` setting.  Some ftp server implementations are configurable.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, what the *server* wants to do has no relevance to the *client* getting the files.

Comment: The command that I see in the example is `put`, not `get`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use ***put*** in **`ftp`**, it is the ***server*** which determines the permissions of the uploaded file.  The [ftp manual page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/ftp-1.html) tells you that `junk.out` is a ***remote*** file:

> **`put local-file`** *[ remote-file ]*
>
> Stores a local file on the remote machine. If *remote-file* is left unspecified, the local file name is used after processing according to any *ntrans* or *nmap* settings in naming the remote file. File transfer uses the current settings for “representation type”, “file structure”, and “transfer mode”.

Assuming you are using Solaris' ftp server (and not some third-party application), the information is in [ftpaccess(4)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5174/ftpaccess-4.html#REFMAN4ftpaccess-4), which describes `/etc/ftpd/ftpaccess`

These settings are relevant for uploaded files (these are independent of the *client* permissions):

> **`defumask`** *umask class*
>
> Set the **`umask`** applied to files created by the FTP server if the remote user is a member of the named *class*. If *class* is not specified, then use the *umask* as the default for classes that do not have one specified. The mode of files created may be specified by using the **`upload`** directive.
>
> **`upload`** [absolute|relative] [`class=`*classname*]... `[-]` *root-dir* *dirglob* yes|no *owner* *group* ***mode*** *[dirs|nodirs]* *[d_mode]*
>
> Define a directory with *dirglob* that permits or denies uploads. If it does permit uploads, all newly created files is owned by owner and group and has their permissions set according to mode. Existing files that are overwritten retains their original ownership and permissions. Directories are matched on a best-match basis. For example:
>
> `upload /var/ftp  *  no`
> `upload /var/ftp /incoming yes ftp daemon 0666`
> `upload /var/ftp /incoming/gifs yes jlc guest 0600 nodirs`
>
> would only allow uploads into `/incoming` and `/incoming/gifs`. Files that were uploaded to `/incoming` are owned by ftp/daemon and have permissions of **0666**. Files uploaded to `/incoming/gifs` are owned by jlc/guest and have permissions of **0600**. The optional **`dirs`** and **`nodirs`** keywords can be specified to allow or disallow the creation of new subdirectories using the **`mkdir`** command. If the **`upload`** command is used, directory creation is allowed by default. To turn it off by default, you must specify a user, group and mode followed by the **`nodirs`** keyword as the first line where the **`upload`** command is used in this file. If directories are permitted, the optional *d_mode* determines the permissions for a newly created directory. If *d_mode* is omitted, the permissions are inferred from mode. The permissions are **0777** if mode is also omitted. The **`upload`** keyword only applies to users who have a home directory of *root-dir*. *root-dir* may be specified as * to match any home directory. The owner or group may each be specified as **`*`**, in which case any uploaded files or directories are created with the ownership of the directory in which they are created. The optional first parameter selects whether *root-dir* names are interpreted as absolute or relative to the current chroot'd environment. The default is to interpret *root-dir* names as absolute. You can specify any number of `class=`*classname* restrictions. If any are specified, this **`upload`** clause only takes effect if the current user is a member of one of the classes.
>
> In the absence of any matching **`upload`** clause, real and guest users can upload files and make directories, but anonymous users cannot. The mode of uploaded files is **0666**. For created directories, the mode is **0777**. Both modes are modified by the current *umask* setting.

Rather wordy, but essentially saying:

- the default permissions on uploaded files are more lax than what you see, and
- **`defumask`** allows the administrator to reduce those permissions globally, and
- **`upload`** allows the administrator to fine-tune things.

In practice, most administrators probably just set **`defumask`**.

The permissions on uploaded files do not depend on your `umask` setting in the shell outside the `ftp` client.  The Solaris `ftpaccess` manual page implies (see its section on *Permission Capabilities*) that clients might be able to specify a umask, but its [client](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/ftp-1.html#scrolltoc) does not list that as a command.

Even with the documented settings, some administrators find quirks, e.g.,

- [Defumask and upload directive in ftp](http://www.unix.com/solaris/245042-defumask-upload-directive-ftp.html)
- [Solaris ftp umask - /etc/ftpd/ftpaccess](http://pg8873.blogspot.com/2014/01/solaris-ftp-umask-etcftpdftpaccess.html)